# Filter managed property with REST api

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, rest, search-results

I'm using Oracle Database and table consist of Title,Description,Language columns. Using BCS and creating BDCM file, I'm able to get all the data from Oracle Database. I could make  managed properties (owsCusTitle,owsCusDESCR,owsLanguage) and link this to the crawled property and everything is OK. Now in my application, I'm showing data using search rest API like this:

```
http://mk3.spha.com/sites/search/_api/search/query?rowlimit=5&selectproperties='owsCusTitle,owsCusDESCR'&sourceid='a3dcf0d0-a1fe-409e-bb84-f407fc4b6be2'&querytext='title:"man*"'
```

But there are many records with owsCusTitle column as blank. I don't want to show those records. Is there any way to filter custom managed property in the query itself ?

Answer (score 1):

I have good news and bad news, but I think I have a fix for the bad news! You CAN "filter" on any queryable managed property. Using your example if you append "owsCustTitle:Ruby" to your query

> querytext='title:"man*" owsCustTitle:Ruby'

would return items that match the title wildcard query and have a CustTitle containing Ruby.

The bad news is you cannot query null. So you can't do "-owsCustTitle=null". The way to fix this is EASY. Just change your query to provide a default value when they encounter null. For example use the string "null". Then the indexer will return the string "null" and you can handle it in a query or in code.

BTW, good on you for using a rowlimit! :)